# Error in 'git2r_clone': unsupported URL protocol

Tags: r, git, rstudio

I am trying to clone a private repo in R using Rstudio with git2r and I am getting the following error:

```
>git2r::clone(url = repo, local_path = dir_name, progress = T, branch = branch, credentials = creds)

cloning into 'C:\Users\...'...
Error in git2r::clone(url = repo, local_path = dir_name, progress = T,  : 
  Error in 'git2r_clone': unsupported URL protocol
```

The credentials variable used in the function `git2r::clone()` is the following,

```
creds <- try(git2r::cred_ssh_key(git2r::ssh_path("id_rsa.pub"),
                                 git2r::ssh_path("id_rsa")), silent = T)
```

I need to clone the repo and install different packages from that repo.
I am trying to do so by using SSH keys.

I was able to do this before, I changed from R-4.1.3 to R-4.3.0 and
installed the same R packages with corresponding version with renv package.

The only difference I can see now is when running `git2r::libgit2_features()` I get the following,

```
git2r::libgit2_features()
$threads
[1] TRUE

$https
[1] TRUE

$ssh
[1] FALSE
```

but in the old R version I would get.

```
git2r::libgit2_features()
$threads
[1] FALSE

$https
[1] TRUE

$ssh
[1] TRUE
```

Is there a way to change ssh to True.
I am using Windows 10, found some examples of how to do this in Linux but not in windows.

Also if I switch back to the old version of R I can clone the repo without any issues, but will need to switch to the new version of R for good soon.

Session info after successfully running (R-4.1.3) and when getting error (R-4.3.0),

```
    # R-4.1.3

> sessioninfo::session_info()
- Session info -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value
 version  R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10)
 os       Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)
 system   x86_64, mingw32
 ui       RStudio
 date     2023-06-23
 rstudio  2022.12.0+353 Elsbeth Geranium (desktop)
 pandoc   NA

- Packages ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 package     * version date (UTC) lib source
 cli           3.3.0   2022-04-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
 git2r         0.30.1  2022-03-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
 renv          0.16.0  2022-09-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
 sessioninfo   1.2.2   2021-12-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)

 [1] C:/.../R/R-413/library

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


# R-4.3.0

> sessioninfo::session_info()
─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 setting  value
 version  R version 4.3.0 (2023-04-21)
 os       Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)
 system   x86_64, mingw32
 ui       RStudio
 date     2023-06-23
 rstudio  2022.12.0+353 Elsbeth Geranium (desktop)
 pandoc   NA

─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 package     * version date (UTC) lib source
 cli           3.3.0   2022-04-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 git2r         0.30.1  2022-03-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 httr          1.4.2   2020-07-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 R6            2.5.1   2021-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
 renv          0.17.3  2023-04-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
 sessioninfo   1.2.2   2021-12-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)

 [1] C:/.../R/R-4.3.0/library

──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

Comment: Have you tried updating `git2r`? Currently the latest version on the CRAN is 0.32 and it may fix your problem?

Comment: Hi. Yes, I tried this already and didnt work.

Comment: Looking at the Github issues, I haven't seen anyone report this problem with Windows (at least not like this). Maybe open an issue at the Github repo? https://github.com/ropensci/git2r/issues